# Should questions asking "does TV/Hollywood" get things right be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I see no value in questions like [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13438/during-a-control-tower-malfunction-can-planes-still-land) and [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13426/how-realistic-is-the-aviation-crisis-in-the-recent-spider-man-movie).  To me, they appear to have nothing to do with aviation, other than in the plot lines.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would say **Yes**, they are on-topic. The plot of the movies is merely a bit of background information on how they got to think of the question, ultimately the real questions are about aviation.

If the question was really just: *Is this movie realistic?*, I would vote to close as **too broad**.

Comment: Looks like the community wishes are clear.  Thanks.